# @Rollback is not working in Spring+Hibernate+Junit testing

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, junit4

while testing a DAO function in spring+hibernate application, data rollback is not happening. I am trying to do the rollback a junit test case by @Rollback annotation

transactionManager config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
```

In my main code I am using hibernateTemplate() to do CRUD operations

test code:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void test_populateObject() throws Exception {


    // TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    // TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

    manualObj= new ManualObj();

    manualObj.setName("TestObj001");
    manualObj.setRefId("TestObj001");
    manualObj.setCallback("TestObj001");
    m
    TestObject obj=orderService.createTestObject(manualObj);

    Assert.assertNotNull(obj);

    // transactionManager.rollback(status);

}
```

The created object is not being deleted by rollback.

So, What could be the reason that @Rollback is n't happening?

Edit 1:

I am using Spring Data JPA and hibernateTemplate based data access in same application. Both using the same transaction manager specified like the above bean config.

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure your test to use the xml configuration, and did you specify the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to run your test?
You can do it like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"testContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class YourTest{ ... }
```

Comment: It is using a test configuration file

Comment: Ok, and are you sure you need the @Rollback annotation? Normally the Transactional annotation already rollbacks changes after each test.

Comment: It does not matter. If rollback happens that is fine. Seems the problem is with the transaction manager. I use two data access tools hibernateTemplate and Spring data JPA. The testcase uses hibernateTemplate to access data but I created transaction manager with org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager. So I am looking on changing it.

Comment: As I said in previous comment, the issue is because of transactionmanager bean configuration. So changed the bean to <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory">
         <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
     </property>
 </bean>. Done.